# Performance of scope = in angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a directive which is something like this:

```
'use strict';
myApp.directive('mySwitchOnOff', [
  '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      replace: false,
      scope: { isActive: '='},
      templateUrl: 'urlToTample',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.toggleVisibility = function(section, module) {
            //Do something with the scope.isActive
        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

This directive uses the `isActive` from the parent scope. The `toggleVisibility` function runs when the user clicks a button. I thought that it was not necessary to bind the `isActive` from the parent, I can find if the button `isActive` by passing the `$event` to the function and check if the target has the active class. So I rewrote the directive like this:

```
'use strict';
myApp.directive('mySwitchOnOff', [
  '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      replace: false,
      templateUrl: 'urlToTample',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.toggleVisibility = function(e, section, module) {
         isActive = j$(e.target).hasClass('active');
         //Do something with the isActive
        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

My questions are: **What do you think is the best from performance/best-practices perspective? To bind the parent scope or pass the $event to the function?**

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question,

I think since you are already calling the digest cycle with the ng-click, not querying the dom (even though hasClass is pretty low performance call) - i.e. Binding the parent scope will be quicker.

The implications of your hasClass: 
(from jquery source)

```
var className = " " + selector + " ",
            i = 0,
            l = this.length;
        for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
            if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 &&
                (" " + this[i].className + " ").replace(rclass, " ").indexOf( className ) >= 0 ) {

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
```

The watch cycle is also not cheap, BUT it happens anyway, so it will be checking references and firing the watch action as needed, but since it's already happening, I think it's faster.

But I am just guessing here :)

Comment: I will wait for more answers and lets see. Thx!